# I need the application to detect what operating system is being run on?

Tags: c#, path, operating-system

I was going over forums yesterday as my issue is that i need my application to detect what operating system it is using and depending on the operating system, the app does a different function.

The best information i found was the Path.PathSeperator. Can anyone confirm if it is correct and tell me how to use it to detect which operating system is being used?

Thank You Very Much! :)

Comment: I am completely new to coding so i dont really know much technical terms. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Environment.OSVersion
```

Property will help ypu to get the Operating System.
Yes you can change some code lines, but to change all codes is not a good idea.

```
if(Environment.OSVersion.VersionString.Contains("Windows"))
{
   //
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: How do i include that in an if function to say if it is windows say hello, but if it is a mono box say bye @Suren Srapyan